# How is Clojure's read-line used properly in a do statement?

Tags: clojure, io

I'm puzzled by the following behavior:

```
(do (println "Say hi.") (println (read-line)))
```

I would expect the message "Say hi." to appear in the console *before* the program blocks and waits for input. Instead the program blocks right away and only outputs "Say hi." *after* the user has responded. What's going on here and how is this program written properly?

Comment: I tested this with Clojure 1.9 and `lein repl` and it worked with both. Are you using a different REPL?

Comment: I'm using the repl that comes with Cursive. It does claim to run Clojure 1.9 upon startup.

Comment: Tested and running as expected ("Say hi." first, followed by wait for input) -  Clojure 1.8 and jEdit repl. I'd say anything which doesn't behave in this manner is very badly broken, because `do` is supposed to guarantee the order of evaluation of the expressions which follow it.

Comment: @BobJarvis, ...but `println` doesn't guarantee anything about when the output buffer will flush, so I'm not convinced that it's "badly broken" in absence thereof. Line buffering is default in most cases when output is to a TTY, but if it's a FIFO rather than a PTY that's used to write to Cursive's GUI, it's easy to see how this could happen.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source of `println` you'll see it calls `prn`. When you look at the source of `prn` you'll see it flushes `*out*` on a newline when `*flush-on-newline*` is bound to true.

What is the value of `*flush-on-newline*` in your REPL?

Comment: It's bound to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a buffering issue. Try issuing a (flush) before the readline call.

Comment: `(do (println "Say hi.") (flush) (read-line))` still produces the same behavior.